# Reply to a specific comment?

Tags: comments, forms

Is there a way to have a hidden field or something in order to place the comment form in a template and have the comments be in reply to a specific comment (so that they would be nested)?

I am going to have an overlay on a page that allows people to comment on a specific comment. So I want to be able to tell the comment form that gets displayed in the overlay which comment the form is in response to.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.You can integrate a custom template for comment detail page where users will start thread on particular comment.

You can create a URL using **add_rewrite_rule**. also add query vars for URL. Here you can get that query var and use **template_redirect** hook to to include a template by apply condition for that query var.

Answer (score -2):

Use this [`get_comments( $args );`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments). You may catch by ID or name.

Comment: I'm not sure how `get_comments()` allows you to reply, could you edit your answer and elaborate?

Comment: <?php
$args = array(
'author_email' => '',    
    'author_url' => '',
    'ID' => '',
    'post_id' => 0,
    'post_author' => '',
    'post_name' => '',
    'post_status' => '',
    'post_type' => '',
);

// The Query
$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments = $comments_query->query( $args );

// Comment Loop
if ( $comments ) {
 foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
  echo '<p>' . $comment->comment_content . '</p>';
 }
} else {
 echo 'No comments found.';
}
?>

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Please use the [edit link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/256472/edit) above, on your answer, to add in this information in a [formatted manner](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). The comment section makes the code and explanation difficult to read.